# Google calendar api wrong time

Tags: php, wordpress, url, google-calendar-api

On a wordpress website I'm using a plugin to add a certain event to your own google calendar. These events are using a 24h format. The problem I'm encountering is that when the plugin sets the time it's using the 24 hour time of the event but when it opens in the google calendar the time is wrongly formatted in am/pm.

In this example the event should start at 19:30 or 7:30pm and end at 21:00 or 9pm.

Link to add event to google calendar:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=A+Title&dates=20190511T193000Z/20190511T210000Z&details=Some+Details&location=street+number,+postalcode+city&sf=true

notice the time format: `&dates=20190511T193000Z/20190511T210000Z`

[image]

I found the file that created the link so I can change it but I don't know how I should change it?

Can I change the google calendar to use the 24h format with an additional variable in the url?

Or should I programatically change the format to am/pm before creating the link? And how should I need to input this in the url?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was't the am or pm formatting time, it was the timezone that wasn't factored in. We live in Belgium so we have a +2 hour time zone that was added to the time in the google calendar. So I fixed the problem by removing 2 hours from the time that I inputted.

**Note:** this solution only works on a fixed timezone of +2. For me this works because this site will only be used in Belgium but I have no clue how to make this work for a variable timezone.